# Clicking "Run C/C++ File" in the top right corner debugs my file instead of running it and displaying the output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm only trying to run a simple helloworld program just to set up my environment (M1 MacBook Pro, Monterey 12.5.1):

My tasks.json looks like this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++17",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
          "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
      }
    ]
  }
```

and my launch.json looks like this:

```
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

and my c_cpp_properties.json looks like this:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I just want the equivalent helloworld executable when I click Run in the top right corner, any help would be appreciated. In addition I'm always asked which compiler I'd like to use, how would I get rid of that question? Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: All of that is supposed to be simpler than a simple, straightforward, `Makefile`...

Comment: Makefiles don't use JSON, so they're not cool.